# glmer throwing fit + rescale errors for a binomial model

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong in this seemingly simple model and am hoping to get some help.

I have a dependent variable that is simply YES or NO responses, where there are 1400 YES responses and 150 NO responses. I've turned the Y/N responses to 0 and 1, respectively, which is what is in the `response` column. I've dummy-coded my effects (each factor has two levels, so I used -1 and 1). I am running a simple intercept-only model:

```
region1_model = glmer(response ~ verb*congruency*pronoun +
                       (1|participant) +
                       (1|item),
                     data = region1_data,
                     family = binomial(link = "cloglog"))
```

But I am encountering the following error:

*Warning: unable to evaluate scaled gradientWarning: Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues*

Different optimizers either give me a singular fit error or the following error:

*Warning: Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio - Rescale variables?*

Am I missing something here? Any help greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: This is a guess only, but it seems that your model have difficulties converging. Have you tried to center and scale your predictor variables? And you should check if your independent variables are highly correlated with each other or the intercept!

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not sure I should center/rescale given that the predictors are categorical (but coded). I will check to see if the independent variables are highly correlated!

Comment: Can you try without interaction effects and see if it converges?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the results of `summary()` ?